# Jquery Add/Remove class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to add select class on clok of paragraph tag. I written code but it is not working. please suggest.

code is given below:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #elm p { background:#FF0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold;}
    .select{ background:#000099;}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#elm').click( function(){ $("p").addClass('hover') });
    function(){ $("p").removeClass('hover') }
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"? You haven't shown a CSS for the `hover` class-name, so if it's doing nothing, *it's doing nothing because you haven't described what it should do*. Did you mean to add/remove the `select` class, by any chance?

Answer (score 5):

Try with `.toggleClass()` like

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#elm').on('click',function(){
         $("p").toggleClass('hover');
      });
 });
```

Comment: <style type="text/css">
p { background:#FF0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold;}
.hover{ background:#000099;}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$('p').on('click', function()
 {$(this).addClass("hover") }
 $(this).removeClass("hover") });
       

});
</script>

</head>


<body>

<div id="elm">
<p>prem</p>
<p>Ravi<p>
<p>Sanjay
<p> 

<p>Anjali<p>
</div>




</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit of a mess to be perfectly honest. Try clean it up a little and you should be able to notice what you're doing wrong.

If I understood your requirements, you want to add/remove a class upon click of the parent div id="elm". If that is the case you can use toggleClass as mentioned by Gautam3164, take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KevinFarrugia/E9Sb5/) although I had to change the code very slightly and made a few assumptions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#elm').click(function(){ 
        $("p").toggleClass('select') 
    });
});
```

Comment: You basically gave the same answer as Gautam, so what's the point?

Comment: I mentioned that I gave the same answer as Gautam, but I corrected some mistakes in the original HTML because it wasn't working (for reasons irrelevant to the question)